# How to convert an array of numeric values as strings to an array of bytes?

Tags: java

How to store for example this string array:

```
{ "128", "128", "127" }
```

to this byte[] array :

```
[128, 128, 127]
```

Comment: use a loop and `Byte.parseByte`. note that the range for byte is `-128 to 127`.

Comment: Please take the time to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. In particular show what you have tried and why it did not work. There is also a very high chance that your question has been asked in which case you should search the duplicate.

Comment: [How to convert string array to int array in java](//stackoverflow.com/q/35358255)

Comment: You might need `Integer.parseInt` and casting it to a byte as 128 is outside the range of a signed byte.

Comment: Hey, peoples... i just lost my mind for a little why you downvoted ?, i have 20 hours programming without rest :) ... One moment i forgot everything that i know :D :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do use `Byte.parseByte(String)` to do this:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(String[] arr) {
    byte[] res = new byte[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        res[i] = Byte.parseByte(arr[i]);

    return res;
}
```

**P.S.**
In `Java` byte values are **[-128; 128)**. Therefore `"128"` will throw `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"128" Radix:10`. The you have to decide what you want to do with those value: throw exception, because of invalid use data; or cast it to the closest byte value, like `"128" -> 127`; or even ignore such values. Then this code could look like this:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(String[] arr) {
    byte[] res = new byte[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        try {
            res[i] = Byte.parseByte(arr[i]);    
        } catch(Exception e) {
            res[i] = // TODO action for incorrect value
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Does that work with `"128"` or will it throw an exception for being out of range?

Comment: @Thilo is will throw exception when it faced with illegal value for `byte`.

Comment: it should be : `(byte) Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);`

Comment: Then you might need to use `Integer.parseInt` instead. The question clearly shows "128" as a valid input.